# Vagrant, Seems like a slow developing process

Tags: web-services, localhost, vagrant, virtual-machine

Im not sure if im understanding vagrant correctly but to my understanding its like a server running in a VM on your computer, which you use instead of your localhost to check to see if stuff is working because your local setup is slightly different to your servers. However is the quickest way to check updates, to git push from your local pc, then git pull on your vagrant VM then load up the website on your local pc to see changes, seems like it would become a painful process after a while compared to the local hosts CTRL+S f5 localhost website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give a few hints:

> its like a server running in a VM on your computer

Vagrant is not a server, its a tool to manage the VMs on your computer, it helps you start, provision, stop or destroy the vm for you. It abstracts the provider you're using (virtualbox, vmware, cloud provider or others) and makes it a single workflow for all your team members.

> However is the quickest way to check updates, to git push from your
>   local pc, then git pull on your vagrant VM then load up the website on
>   your local pc to see changes

Not sure what you're working on but most likely, [sync folder](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html) should help you avoid doing that. I already explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537027/using-a-local-editor-with-vagrant/32538481#32538481) how you can work with sync folder

Basically, when you use sync folder, when you modify a file from your host, the same file will be modified on the vm, so you do not need all the git things. Changes are not immediate but most people can accommodate.

as an example, you can add

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/ssh/www", "/var/www"
```

This will map my local folder `/Users/fhenri/project/examples/vagrant/ssh/www` with vm folder `/var/www`

> Vagrant, Seems like a slow developing process

This might be a true and there are a few blogs (do not retrieve them at the moment) that deal with that. so what are the solutions ?

Depending the infrastructure you try to replicate using vagrant, but if you're a single developper you can check [docker](http://www.docker.com), if you're not confortable with docker, vagrant can really support you there and you can declare [docker as vagrant provider](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/), again there are a few blog post that deal with that with some benchmark, you can really benefit if you struggle with vagrant performance.

I hope it helps a bit

Comment: thanks, is there a way to use a shared folder straight into /var/www?

Comment: yes, you can, editing my answer with the example - be careful though that if you already have files in this folder (`/var/www` on the vm) they will be not be accessible when you run `vagrant up`, only the files from your host folder will be visible