# Ruby on Rails development on Mac vs Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vagrant

I'm developing several apps using Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X Yosemite. My main deploying OS is Debian 8 x64.

I heard a lot about Vagrant. Should I use it? What advantages it gives me? Will it speed up my workflow or worse: slow it down?

Can I use it as a staging server for deploying?

Comment: Good you heard about vagrant, you can check the [why vagrant?](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/why-vagrant/index.html) I suggest you try just a bit (tons of tutorials how to start) not even with provisioning (leave it for the next step) and see if it benefits you

Comment: @FredericHenri thanks for the link! I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant creates a virtual machine and pretty much it's only advantage is that you can create virtual machine image, witch will speed up development environment setup (which might be handy if you are planning to hire a lot of developers in closest future). It will also create a completely isolated environment, so you can be sure that other application won't affect the one you're working on.

There are still quite a lot of issues (at least there was the last time I tried it) with file synchronization between host and VM, making development with Vagrant extremely slow (had to wait 20 seconds per page). It is not an easy task to create a vagrant file which would work on all OS of the host. Also it will consume much more of your machine resources.

It can be however a very good match for staging server, as it allows quick destruction and recreation of your VM and provides good isolation, so you can test your deployment scripts without any risk.

Comment: If I'll use it as staging server it would save a lot of time. But if you're right about delays: vagrant will just slow my workflow if I use it as development server. I tend to work very fast and it'll just piss me off like the old time I used Dreamweaver with git (not for RoR).

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554044/4296747) are some thoughts on is vagrant slow or what can be improved to work faster (20 sec per page seems like an old time)

Comment: @FredericHenri - Synced folders were the reason of that slowness. :) I had to create a VM which would work for my co-workers (and they worked on windows, bleh!) so NFS was off the table. Default VirtualBox shared folder are quite slow, and in rails development the entire application reloads per each request - read speed is critical.

Comment: @BroiSatse ah clear, vagrant author discussed [performance here](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines) and clearly if you can run nfs its black & white. I share dev with windows users too but I do use vmware provider (as our box is setup for both providers) and I can't complain much with recent version of vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Ruby on Rails is limited but I am developing using Django and I run all of my apps on Vagrant. I believe that the idea of using Vagrant is the same regardless of technology.

The main reason that I use it is the fact that you can set up Vagrant to copy your deployment environment. This means that you can be (almost 100%) sure that your production code is going to work when deployed (because you are coding and testing in the same environment).

Additional benefit is the fact that the more apps you have the harder it becomes to keep track of all of the packages and dependencies needed. With Vagrant you can set your environment to meet the exact criteria for every project.

Regarding weather it will slow or speed up your work. I think this depends a bit on your coding style but Vagrant shares the folders of your project so any changes made in your code will be reflected in Vagrant. You will just need to forward the port of your app and you will almost fail to notice that Vagrant is between you and your project. That is if everything is set up correctly.

Hope my answer helps a bit.

Comment: I have a friend who develops using Django. It's shares a lot with RoR. So you sort of right: the setup of a vm will share a lot.